# Oracle query Java EE, Entity Manager

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa

If I have an Oracle database, with structure, SCHEMA/TABLE1 SCHEMA/TABLE2 and I want to create a query to select all rows from Table1, would it be,

"Select x from SCHEMA.TABLE1 x"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an entity such as:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="SCHEMA", name="TABLE1")
public class Table1Class { 
 ...
}
```

Then, the following [basic JPQL Query](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html#jpa_overview_query_basic) would select all the `Table1Class` entities:

`Select x from Table1Class x`.

Summing up, you *don't* need to (not that you can, either) specify schema and table name on JPQL queries, just the class name the table is mapped to.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, however, when I try it with x.* I get "Encountered ". *" at character 9, but expected: ["*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ....." and when I try it without .* I get SCHEMA.TABLE1 is not a recognised entity, any ideas? I am using Geronimo, Eclipse, OpenJPA and Oracle DB.